# Firebase query is not populating array for table view. How can I resolve this issue?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I have written a firebase query that gets information from my Competition db and then loads it into my distanceData (which is of type distanceModel, a class that I created) before populating the table view. However, the table view is not being populated.

**Photo of Firebase db**

[image]

**Photo of distanceModel class**

[image]

I tried putting print statements in the query to see if the data is being retrieved correctly, but nothing is being printed so the problem is most likely with the query.

```
var distanceData = [distanceModel]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate=self
    tableView.dataSource=self
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 200

    refUser = Database.database().reference().child("userInfo");

    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let query = refUser?.queryOrdered(byChild: "userId").queryEqual(toValue: "\(userID)")
    query?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let childSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
            var dict = childSnap.value as! [String: Any]
            let level=dict["level"] as! String
            if (level=="Beginner") {
                self.refCompetition = Database.database().reference().child("competition1");
            }

            else if (level=="Intermediate") {
                self.refCompetition = Database.database().reference().child("competition2");
            }

            else {
                self.refCompetition = Database.database().reference().child("competition3");
            }
        }
    })
```

retrieve the posts and listen for changes

```
refCompetition?.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        for users in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let userObject = users.value as? [String: AnyObject]
            let userName = userObject?["name"] as! String?
            let userDistance = userObject?["distance"] as! String?
            print(userName)
            print(userDistance)


            let dist = distanceModel(name: userName,distance: userDistance)

            self.distanceData.append(dist)
        }
    })

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Number of Rows

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return distanceData.count;
}
```

Contents for each cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DistanceCell", for: indexPath) as! DistanceCell

    let dist: distanceModel
    dist = distanceData[indexPath.row]
    cell.nameLabel.text = dist.name
    cell.distanceLabel.text = dist.distance

    cell.rankNumber.text = String (indexPath.row+1)

    return cell
}
```

It should get the data from the appropriate competition db and then render the results onto the table view.

Comment: 1. Why aren't you using Firestore? 2. Avoid all of that dangerous force unwrapping. 3. If you're reloading a table on the fly with realtime updates, you better load those results into a temporary array or else you will be susceptible to index-out-of-range errors that will crash your app. 4. Typically, when you observe for realtime changes, you only need to create an observer (not both a getter and an observer; the observer will get data immediately).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about that?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 200

    refUser = Database.database().reference().child("userInfo");

    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let query = refUser?.queryOrdered(byChild: "userId").queryEqual(toValue: "\(userID)")
    query?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let childSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
            var dict = childSnap.value as! [String: Any]
            let level = dict["level"] as! String

            if (level == "Beginner") {
                self.refCompetition = Database.database().reference().child("competition1");
            }
            else if (level == "Intermediate") {
                self.refCompetition = Database.database().reference().child("competition2");
            }
            else {
                self.refCompetition = Database.database().reference().child("competition3");
            }

            self.refCompetition?.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                for users in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    let userObject = users.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let userName = userObject?["name"] as! String?
                    let userDistance = userObject?["distance"] as! String?
                    print(userName)
                    print(userDistance)

                    let dist = distanceModel(name: userName,distance: userDistance)
                    self.distanceData.append(dist)
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            })        
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your self.tableView.reloadData() call into the Observer like below

```
refCompetition?.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        for users in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let userObject = users.value as? [String: AnyObject]
            let userName = userObject?["name"] as! String?
            let userDistance = userObject?["distance"] as! String?
            print(userName)
            print(userDistance)


            let dist = distanceModel(name: userName,distance: userDistance)

            self.distanceData.append(dist)
        }

self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Comment: Brandon, thank you. I think the main issue is with the query itself, however, since when I tried to print the name and distance, nothing was printed. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: If you'd like to put a private Repo up I can have a look for you but without that I won't be able to help you more than I already have unfortunately